# how do i get the value of the text box that is related to the specific option value when selected

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

how do i get the value of the text box that is related to the specific option value when selected in servlet/jsp as i want to put it in the database.for e.g., when i select the option red then it's related text box(which will have a default value) will be activated or appeared. I know to get the value of the selected option but i don't know to get the value of it's related option. Is there any other way to do it ..??Is there any one can help me please..!!! ??

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckColors(val)
{  
var element=document.getElementById('Color');
var element1=document.getElementById('Dolor');
var element2=document.getElementById('Polor');

element.style.display='none';
element1.style.display='none';
element2.style.display='none';

if(val=='others')
{
element.style.display='block';  

}

else if(val=='red')
{

 element1.style.display='block';
}
else if(val=='blue')
{
 element2.style.display='block'; 
}


}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
<option>pick a color</option>  
 <option value="red">RED</option>
 <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
 <option value="others">others</option>
 </select>
 other:<input type="text" placeholder="other" name="Color" id="Color"         style='display:none;'/>
 red:<input type="text" placeholder="red" name="Dolor" id="Dolor" style='display:none;'/>
 blue:<input type="text" placeholder="blue" name="Polor" id="Polor" style='display:none;'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually data from a HTML form will be POST'd to a servlet.  The filled fields will be sent to the servlet.  Are you using any framework?  You can also use Jquery to extract data from you DOM and use AJax to POST the data.

Comment: I am not using any frameworks for my this project. Just plain jsp/servlet.

Comment: Sorry your HTML should have a FORM element with the target being the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you reading about Java JSP/Servlets. Follow a simple tutorial, google it!

To communicate with a web page and your code you will need to handle it with a submit form.
There are different ways to achieve this, but simple is to use a *form* element, and an action and method. Either you add a submit call in your javascript CheckColors or apply a submit button when color has been chosen.

HTML request page --> Jsp or Servlet --> HTML response page

change:

```
<html> 
<head>  
...
<body>
<form name='theform' action='/javacode.jsp' method='post'>
 <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
 ...
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if you use a jsp or servlet, doesnt matter. This is simple demo.

In your javacode then, you do read the request with getParameter("color")

> Read as I said a JSP / Servlet tutorial.

*A tutorial with similar flow, using color as an example:*

http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/A%20servlet%20example.aspx

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

Comment: I want to retrieve the value which is in the text box which gets act displayed when its related option value is chosen.How do i do it..?? I can get the other values by using getParameter method but i can't use the similar way to get the value which i want.